# iOS: Change background color of a button when different button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have quiz app which has 4 answers and one of them is right and they are all within a collection view. When a user clicks the wrong answer, I need to show them the right answer by changing button color for the right answer. I got access to that button but for some reason, the button color is not changing. Am I missing something?

```
-(void)selectedAnswer:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"ANswer Selected : %ld",(long)sender.tag);
    NSLog(@"CurrentAnswer : %@",_currentAnswer);
    NSLog(@"Question : %@",[[GameManager manager] getCurrentQuestion]);
    int correctAnswer = [[_currentAnswer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] intValue];
    NSLog(@"Correct Answer Is : %d",correctAnswer);
    if (correctAnswer == sender.tag){
        NSLog(@"Correct Answer Index : %@",_currentAnswerIndex);
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        //[self updateScore:true];
        //[self nextQuestion];
    }else{
          NSLog(@"Correct Answer Index : %@",_currentAnswerIndex);
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        SignCollectionViewCell * cell = (SignCollectionViewCell *)[self collectionView:self._collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_currentAnswerIndex integerValue] inSection:0]];
        NSLog(@"cell Tag %@",cell.answerButton);

        cell.answerButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];//NOT WORKING
       // [self updateScore:false];
        //[self nextQuestion];
    }
}
```

Debugger: Color seems to be there

[image]

Comment: Are each of your UIButtons' tag values set in such a way that the intValue of the correctAnswer would match their tag value?

Comment: Don't just stare at the code wondering what the problem is. You have a debugger. Debug! Step through the code and make sure all the values are what you expect.

Comment: Everything is working properly except button color change. @benhameen

Comment: I agree with matt, my thoughts are that you may not be accessing the correct SignCollectionViewCell, so do your best to make sure that you are, perhaps by changing other elements of the button/cell to be sure. You could also try using `UIButton *correctButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:correctAnswer];` and see if that works for you, though I personally do not prefer the use of tags.

Comment: @matt background color seems to be there but I cant see it

Comment: another way is to use a `BOOL showSolution` to enable it and then reload the collection view

Comment: @rob180 Personally I think you've reached the heart of the matter. You should expand on that, as an answer.

Comment: I personally dont think reloading a collection view is good for me because I will be showing that for 0.5 sec. I am reloading collection view right after for the next question. My question is why would sender.background works but not the other? @rob180

Comment: Try `[answerButton setBackgroundImage:color forState:state];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy solution is to use a control variable, and when you want to show the correct solution you change it and reload the collection view. something like

```
if(shouldShowAnswer){
  cell.answerButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]
}else{
  cell.answerButton.backgroundColor = defaultColor
}
```